# Calculating one fee below a certain amount and another fee above a certain amount

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the following:

I have to calculate a fee of 5% for any amount between -100 USD and 100 USD, and a fee of 8% for any amount below -100 USD or above -100 USD and then sum both of these fee amounts.

E.g. A client has a negative balance of -123 USD (I am looking to calculate 5% for the first -100 USD and 8% for the rest -23 USD). Or other way around if he has a balance of 123 USD (I am looking to calculate 5% for the first 100 USD and 8% for the rest 23 USD).

I would greatly appreciate the help, because I cannot seem to figure out how to incorporate that it calculates both fees with different rates and then sums them together.

Comment: I would look to use the absolute value as the number is the same irrespective of sign, which reduces the calculations...

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to first write down what you want to achieve, and later turn this into an Excel formula.
Basically one helpful thing is the absolute value:

- If Abs(x)<= 100 Then Fee = 5/100 * x
  Else: Fee = 8/100 * x
- Calculate the sum

All those things can be done using basic Excel functions: `ABS()` for absolute value, `IF(cond,action_true,action_false)` and simple adding.